# Is volume label information for an external hard drive saved on the drive itself?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have an external hard drive, which I use to transfer files between two computers (computer A and computer B).  Suppose I rename the external hard drive (i.e., rename the hard drive's *label*) in Windows 7 on computer A by going to **Start > Computer**.  Then, in the **Computer** window, right-click the external hard drive `Seagate Expansion Drive`, left-click **Rename**, type the new label (e.g., `My External Drive`), and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  The drive formerly known as `Seagate Expansion Drive` is now `My External Drive` on computer A.

But now suppose I eject the external hard drive from computer A and connect it to computer B, which is also running Windows.  (Computer A is *definitely* running Windows 7, but Computer B may be running Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, *or* 10.)  **When I connect it to computer B, will the drive still have the label `My External Drive`?**

In other words, is the drive (volume) label information saved on the drive itself?  Or is it saved on the operating system (internal) drive on computer A?

Answer (score 2):

## YES!!!

The drive's name and properties are stored on it. Since all versions of Windows since Windows XP can read the NTFS file format (and the FAT32 format), The drive should be readable and the drive's name and properties will be readable by the other operating system.

Comment: In NTFS the label is located on the special file $Volume (can't be seen in explorer), the attribute name is $VOLUME_NAME.